# How to make a bash script execute on file saves?

Tags: macos, bash

If its possible I was hoping someone could tell me how to make a bash script execute on once for every file save in a directory (preferably in any subsequent directories as well, but I'll take what I can get). I did some googling, didn't find anything, and and am pretty new to bash scripting so I turned to SO.

I would also take a polling system that checks if files have changed every so often but I'm not sure how that would work either.

Oh also I'm on a Mac if that matters.

Thanks!

Comment: Definitely does matter, btw. If the target were Linux, I'd be suggesting incron instead.

Comment: @ChristianFritz thx for linking the other question! I'm going to leave this up so that people can find an answer better with out knowing to search for watch or inotifywait.

Comment: sounds good. I agree that under the original title it's hard to find.